# How to rename all keys in a serde_json::Map?

Tags: dictionary, rust, serde, serde-json

Let's say I have a `&mut std::collections::HashMap`, and I want to turn all the keys into uppercase. The following code does the trick:

```
use std::collections::HashMap;

fn keys_to_upper<T>(map: &mut HashMap<String, T>) {
    let mut tmp = Vec::with_capacity(map.len());
    for (key, val) in map.drain() {
        tmp.push((key.to_ascii_uppercase(), val));
    }
    for (key, val) in tmp {
        map.insert(key, val);
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, I don't have a `HashMap` but a [`&mut serde_json::Map`](https://docs.serde.rs/serde_json/struct.Map.html), and I want to turn all the keys into uppercase. There is no `.drain()` method. I could use `.into_iter()` instead, but that would only give me mutable references to the keys and values. To insert them into the map again I would have to clone them, which would hurt performance.

Is there some way here to get around the absense of the `.drain()` method?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A nice tool in your Rust programmer toolbox: [`std::mem::take`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.take.html).
This lets you change a `&mut T` to a `T` if the type implements default (if it doesn't, but the type still has a dummy/cheap value you can use, then [`std::mem::replace`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/mem/fn.replace.html) is your function of choice).

Applied to your current use-case this gives:

```rust
use serde_json::{Map, Value};

fn keys_to_upper<T>(map: &mut Map<String, Value>) {
    *map = std::mem::take(map)
        .into_iter()
        .map(|(k, v)| (k.to_ascii_uppercase(), v))
        .collect();
}
```